# Matplotlib 3D Bar chart: axis issue

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, mplot3d

I am having issue with getting data on x,y,z axis..below is my code. Is there any issue with the way i have defined range(dx,dy.dz) for different axis.

```
result=[['122', '109', '2343', '220', '19'],
 ['15', '407', '37', '10', '102'],
 ['100', '100', '100', '100', '100'],
 ['113', '25', '19', '31', '112'],
 ['43', '219', '35', '33', '14'],
 ['132', '108', '256', '119', '14'],
 ['22', '48', '352', '51', '438']]

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.dates as dates

def format_date(x, pos=None):
     return dates.num2date(x).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

xpos=[10/11/2013,10/12/2013,10/13/2013,10/14/2013,10/15/2013]
ypos=['A1','C1','G1','M1','M2','M3','P1']
zpos=result

dx=[5]
dy=[7]
dz=[7]
ax1.w_xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))
ax1.bar3d(xpos,ypos,zpos,dx,dy,dz,color='#00ceaa')
plt.show()
```

I am getting below error:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-02cd8e7ee228> in <module>()
     18 dz=[17]
     19 ax1.w_xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))
---> 20 ax1.bar3d(xpos,ypos,zpos,dx,dy,dz,color='#00ceaa')
     21 plt.show()

C:\Users\Andalib\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py in bar3d(self, x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color, zsort, *args, **kwargs)
   2316             maxx = max(xi + dxi, maxx)
   2317             miny = min(yi, miny)
-> 2318             maxy = max(yi + dyi, maxy)
   2319             minz = min(zi, minz)
   2320             maxz = max(zi + dzi, maxz)

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Comment: Your `xpos` should be a list of strings `["10/11/2013", "10/12/2013", "10/13/2013", "10/14/2013", "10/15/2013"]`

Comment: I did that...but still getting same error as mentioned above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are the following issues in your code:

- `xpos` and `ypos` are usually a flatenned meshgrid with the positions of the base of the 3D bars
- `zpos` gives the position of the base along the `z` axis, which is usually zero unless you want the bars looking like they are flying
- `xpos`, `ypos` and `zpos` must have the same flattened shape and must all be `1-D` arrays

Since you know the positions for each value you can use a `np.arange()` to create the positions `xpos` and `ypos`, and afterwards set the tick labels.

The example code is:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

result=[['122', '109', '2343', '220', '19'],
 ['15', '407', '37', '10', '102'],
 ['100', '100', '100', '100', '100'],
 ['113', '25', '19', '31', '112'],
 ['43', '219', '35', '33', '14'],
 ['132', '108', '256', '119', '14'],
 ['22', '48', '352', '51', '438']]

result = np.array(result, dtype=np.int)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=150)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xlabels = np.array(['10/11/2013', '10/12/2013', '10/13/2013',
                    '10/14/2013', '10/15/2013'])
xpos = np.arange(xlabels.shape[0])
ylabels = np.array(['A1','C1','G1','M1','M2','M3','P1'])
ypos = np.arange(ylabels.shape[0])

xposM, yposM = np.meshgrid(xpos, ypos, copy=False)

zpos=result
zpos = zpos.ravel()

dx=0.5
dy=0.5
dz=zpos

ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticks(xpos + dx/2.)
ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(xlabels)

ax1.w_yaxis.set_ticks(ypos + dy/2.)
ax1.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(ylabels)

values = np.linspace(0.2, 1., xposM.ravel().shape[0])
colors = cm.rainbow(values)
ax1.bar3d(xposM.ravel(), yposM.ravel(), dz*0, dx, dy, dz, color=colors)
plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

you can also use the `values` array proportional to `dz`:

```
values = (dz-dz.min())/np.float_(dz.max()-dz.min())
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to assign random color to each row or line?

Comment: q@user3632319 I've updated the answer adding colors to each bar. Note that you can use any color scale contained in `matplotlib.cm`, I used the `rainbow` but you shoud check the others as well...

Comment: @user3632319 to change only one row or column you have to play with the `values` array...

Comment: @SaulloG.P.Castro Nice, I ran exactly the same code but I'm not getting the black strokes around each bar, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, your `result` list has to contain integers, and not strings. You can convert it to integers with list comprehension:

```
result = [[int(i) for i in sublist] for sublist in result]
```

Or, better yet, you can use `np.array`:

```
import numpy as np
result = np.array(result, dtype=np.int)
```

**Update**:

As `bar3d` [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.bar3d) (and [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html)) suggest, `ipos` arrays should hold the positions of bars; `di` arrays should hold the distances between bars. Your `xpos` and `ypos` lists hold what is called the tick labels. So, you need to change these and then set tick labels of relevant axes to given `xpos` and `ypos`. According tho the example provided, you can do it in the following way:

```
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(np.arange(5)+0.5, np.arange(7)+0.5)
xpos = xpos.flatten()
ypos = ypos.flatten()
zpos = np.zeros(5*7)
dx = np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = result.flatten()
xticks=['','10/11/2013','10/12/2013','10/13/2013','10/14/2013','10/15/2013']
yticks=['','A1','C1','G1','M1','M2','M3','P1']
ax1.set_xticklabels(xticks)
ax1.set_yticklabels(yticks)
```

Comment: I have converted my result list with reference to your above code..but still getting the  same error

Comment: Yes, it seems that `bar3d` works the different way altogether. i'll edit my answer.